# Submit trial version of WP7 application

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have written a WP7 app which includes source code for both a trial and full version using, for example,

```
if (App.IsTrial){
      // show trial mode
 }else{
    // show full mode
}
```

This means that the trial version and full version are in the same XAP file. When I submit the app to the market do I submit each version separately or do I submit once for both versions.

Answer (score 5):

You would submit it once. The licensing on the Windows Phone will handle if the application should be run as a trial or as a full version.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967554(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You only need to submit your single release build.

On the Submission page that allows setting of your app price you will find a check box that says "allow trials to be downloaded"  Check that checkbox.